# multiple mysql echos in html

Tags: php, echo

I guess I have a really simple question. I have a simple HTML page which I want to fill up with words from a mysql database.

Therefore I wrote this little test page. My problem is, that the first echo "Picture" works fine but the second one "Name" won't output anything. It works only the first time. If I add this:

```
$sql = <<<SQL
    SELECT *
    FROM `Database1`
    WHERE `id` = 1 
SQL;

if(!$result = $db->query($sql)){
    die('There was an error running the query [' . $db->error . ']');
}
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
```

before the second echo "Name" everything works fine.

```
<?php
$db = new mysqli('', '', '', '');

if($db->connect_errno > 0){
    die('Unable to connect to database [' . $db->connect_error . ']');
}

$sql = <<<SQL
    SELECT *
    FROM `Database1`
    WHERE `id` = 1 
SQL;

if(!$result = $db->query($sql)){
    die('There was an error running the query [' . $db->error . ']');
}
?>

<html>

<img src="<?php
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    echo $row['Picture'];}
?>" height="270">

some more html...

<?php
    echo $row['Name'] . '<br />';
?>                          

even more html...

<?php
    mysqli_close ($con);
?>  

</html>
```

Is this the way to go? Or did I miss something?

Thank you!

Comment: If you will notice here `echo $row['Picture'];}` you have ended the `while` loop of php. So whatever comes after it, will not show.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solutions by myself: The trick is to move the pointer to row 0 again after the while loop:

```
mysqli_data_seek($result, 0);
```

[Docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.data-seek.php)

Comment: you can also save all records to an array variable (with `fetch_all`) and then cycle on the array and not on the results.